# Postgres changeset with column TEXT not working with Liquibase 3.6.2 and Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am working with the new Spring Boot 2.1.0 version.  In Spring Boot 2.1.0, Liquibase was updated from 3.5.5 to 3.6.2.  I've noticed several things in my change sets are no long working.

```
-- test_table.sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (
   id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   --Works fine as TEXT or VARCHAR with Liquibase 3.5 which is bundled with Spring Boot version 2.0.6.RELEASE
   --Will only work as VARCHAR with Liquibase 3.6.2 which is bundled with Spring Boot version 2.1.0.RELEASE and above
   worksheet_data TEXT
);
-- test_table.csv
id,worksheet_data
1,fff

-- Liquibase Changeset
    <changeSet id="DATA_01" author="me" runOnChange="false">
    <loadData
            file="${basedir}/sql/data/test_table.csv"
            tableName="test_table"/>
    </changeSet>
```

This will not work.  I am presented with this odd stacktrace.  It complains it can't find liquibase/changelog/fff which I'm not referencing at all in the changeset.  The "fff" coincidentally matches the data value in table_test.csv.

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/changelog/data_nonprod.xml::DATA_NONPROD_02::scott_winters:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: class path resource [liquibase/changelog/fff] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at net.migov.amar.MiAmarApiApplication.main(MiAmarApiApplication.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set liquibase/changelog/data_nonprod.xml::DATA_NONPROD_02::scott_winters:
         Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: class path resource [liquibase/changelog/fff] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:78) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:305) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: class path resource [liquibase/changelog/fff] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.applyColumnParameter(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:191) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.attachParams(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:110) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.statement.BatchDmlExecutablePreparedStatement.attachParams(BatchDmlExecutablePreparedStatement.java:51) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.execute(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:81) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquib

ase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:115) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1229) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [liquibase/changelog/fff] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:556) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.getResourceAsStream(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:281) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.toCharacterStream(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:241) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.statement.ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.applyColumnParameter(ExecutablePreparedStatementBase.java:184) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

If I change TEXT to VARCHAR it works.  From my understanding these column types are the same in postgres, so I can work around this.  However, this is frustrating, and I don't see this new behavior documented.  From this link 3.6.2 is advertised as a "drop in" change (http://www.liquibase.org/2018/04/liquibase-3-6-0-released.html).

I would like to use the new features of Spring Boot 2.1.0, but I cannot specify liquibase 3.5.5 in my build because Spring Boot will complain about incompatible versions.  This is just one issue I'm seeing with changesets that worked in 3.5.5.  Maybe the folks at Spring should consider rolling back the version of liquibase.

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATED**
I have created a sample Spring Boot project to demonstrate this:  https://github.com/pcalouche/postgres-liquibase-text

Comment: can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: @bilak I updated my question to include that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PCalouche could you please share a small project related with this issue?

Comment: @nextsoft I probably should have done that from the start.  This small project demonstrates the issue https://github.com/pcalouche/postgres-liquibase-text.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ok, I'll see it later, @PCalouche thansk!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They broke `TEXT` data type. Try to use `VARCHAR`

May be it could be interesting too https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-865

You can find all availible types here https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core

I think that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` should works for you

Also the closed issue with `CLOB` type for Postgresql https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2220